# Pure css gradually change text on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to gradually change an element's text while hovering, however it's not working for me.

I have this CSS:

```
.author-details > div a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    float: none !important;
    background-color: #1ABC9C;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2% 3% 2% 3%;
    border-radius: 7%;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;

    -webkit-transition: background 0.35s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 0.35s linear;
    -ms-transition: background 0.35s linear;
    -o-transition: background 0.35s linear;
    transition: background 0.35s linear;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 13px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 13px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 13px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
}

.author-details > div a:after {
  content: 'Others';
}

.author-details > div a:hover {
    background-color: #5DADE2;
}

.author-details > div a:hover:after {
    -webkit-animation:fade-in 0.35s ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in{
0%{
    opacity:1;
    top:0px;
}
50%{
    opacity:0;
    top:-5px;
    content: 'Me';
}
100%{
    opacity:1;
    top:-5px;
}
```

}

And this HTML:

```
<div><label>View as:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label> <a href ="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con1');"></a></div>
```

However when I'm hovering on the element the text doesn't change. I want to make it change to "Me" when I'm hovering over it and return to "Others" when I'm not. How can I do that?

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2fgy912p/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ysjoLz2u/1/ 

check this for your reference , I know it;s not fixing your issue but it will guide as basic implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qbdvob

This effect works by using hover state to set opacity of absolutely positioned elements' opacity on and off. And they have transition applied so fade in and out effect is achieved.

Jade styled html:

```
.widget
  span view as:
  input(type='checkbox',id='toggle')
  label.select(for='toggle')
    .default others
    .hovered you
```

Css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.widget {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.widget span {
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 30px;
}
label.select {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #3ce;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
label.select .default,
label.select .hovered {
  transition: opacity 1s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
}
label.select .hovered {
  opacity: 0;
}

label.select:hover {
  background-color: #36f;
}

label.select .default {
  opacity: 1;
}
label.select .hovered {
  opacity: 0;
}
label.select:hover .default {
  opacity: 0;
}
label.select:hover .hovered {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining text to replace when `hover` the link. Should be:

```
.author-details > div a:after {
  content: 'Others';
}
.author-details > div a:hover:after {
  content: 'Me';
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/2fgy912p/3/

**EDIT1:**

I make a few changes to add transitions. See if this is want you want: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/2fgy912p/7/

**EDIT2:**

I hardcoded the `top` property on each element, that should work, although I see working fine. Check: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/2fgy912p/9/

Comment: The text fades out then fades in. so I want it to change after it fades out

Comment: @lmgonzalves Your new fiddle has an odd glitch on hover. The `me` text pops at the top for a millisecond before coming in.

Comment: I don't see that @JClaspill, but I add prefixes in this new edit just in case. I am using Firefox.

Comment: Still has that glitch. 'Me' appears on the top of the button and then the transition is made

Comment: I don't know then. I can see it properly from here, using Firefox, but the browser should not matter :(